# How to deal with dotdefender web scraping blocks python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I'm scraping websites for a research project, and for the first time I've encountered'

```
 dotdefender blocked your request."
```

I'm not doing anything malicious; just scraping basic information. Is it possible to let them know this and/or overcome the block?

Here's the [site](http://www.sullcrom.com/lawyers/GeorgeH-White).

Answer (score 2):

Some sites will block scraping even if it is not malicious. You can try to run the scraping through a proxy but depending on how quickly you are scraping and the quality of the proxy you may still eventually get blocked. If you are doing a low amount of data collection the proxy should work, but if you are doing a larger quantity you may want to consider a premium service, rather an [IP rotation service](http://www.ntrepidcorp.com/ion/)(think premium proxy).

Also you could try [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) but you may still run into speed issues.

For Proxies there are plenty of free and paid options but the quality is hard to measure.